# How do I keep a word like "isn't" intact with a default token split?

Tags: c++, stanford-nlp

Using Stanford's `TokenScanner` class in C++, how do I keep a word like "isn't" intact, because the default token splits it into `isn`, `'`, `t`.

```
string word = "This isn't me";
TokenScanner scanner(word);
scanner.ignoreWhitespace();
while(true){
    if(!scanner.hasMoreTokens()) break;
    string token = scanner.nextToken();
    cout << token <<endl;
}
```

This current code, displays:

> "This" \n "isn" \n "\'" \n "t" \n "me" \n

as the separate words gotten from the token.

Comment: Is there any way to make the tokenizer not interpret `'` as a token?

Answer (score 0):

Use `scanner.addWordCharacters"'"` to add the single quote to the list of characters that are accepted in a word.